# How to read Binary image(tif) in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tiff, binaryfiles, gdal

I have tif image and have to read it using visual studio 2010 in c++. i have included the libraries of GDAL, but unable to proceed further. I have read "GDAL APT TUTORIAL" [Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html). but still showing much errors as it is not accepting the pszfilename (extension of my image).
can anyone help me what to do next??

Answer (score 2):

Find documentation on TIFF [file structure](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf), learn the tags present in a tiff file, look through the file with your favourite hex editor. Or find a library for reading tiff files, there was one called [libtiff](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/)...

Comment: I have found the library for reading tiff file i.e GDAL... but unable to use it... how to code in c++ using those libraries to get the output in binaryform.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with GDAL. You can build libtiff from sources, then if it doesn't work for you you can always step through with a debugger to see where it fails. Unfortunally I don't have a sample at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work when using the right (.tif) extension?
If you can use another library, Qt has a plugin to read tiff images. And you can give it only the content of the file, ignoring the file extension.

Comment: No.. it doesnt work.. infact it is not accepting the path at all... well i am using GDAL libraries. but dont know how to code in c++ to get output binary form of tiff image.